# save multiple record in backbone model?

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, backbone-model

Am trying to save model in backbone. This code is working
`myModel.save({'title':title},{changed:'title'});`

But am not sure why it is not working without changed attribute. `myModel.save({'title':title});`

Also how do I save multiple records using this?

Comment: Model's [save](http://backbonejs.org/#Model-save) method deals with **single** record. If you want to handle multiple records you have to use [Collection](http://backbonejs.org/#Collection)

Comment: One uses a collection for _multiple_ records.

Comment: "Not working" isnt really a good description. Add an error handler to your save and tell us, if anything goes wrong. Do you encounter any errors?

Comment: My collection has multiple models and those each models has multiple attributes. I want to update those all attribute in one particular model in save function.

Answer (score 0):

To save multiple attributes for a single model, include all the changed attributes and their corresponding values in a single `object {}`.

For example:

```
myModel.save({
  attributeA: valueA,
  attributeB: valueB,
  attributeC: valueC
});
```

It may help to read through [backbone's annotated source regarding the save function](http://backbonejs.org/docs/backbone.html#section-81).

To save attributes on all models in a collection, you could iterate over the collection, possibly using [underscore's each function](http://underscorejs.org/#each).

For example:

```
myCollection.each(function (myModel) {
  myModel.save({
    attributeA: valueA,
    attributeB: valueB,
    attributeC: valueC
  });
})
```

Note: Since these examples are out of context, unique values for the attributes would have to be handled with additional logic.

Comment: Thanks! I tried this. But my save works only with myModel.save({'title':title},{changed:'title'}); changed attribute. If I take off 'changed' it does not send value to backend. Not sure how to structure this for multiple attributes. Any idea?

Comment: Got my answer. Changed attribute is something used in my sync function and i have to make it as an array to pass multiple attributes. Thanks!!!

Comment: Glad you figured it out.